# How do I get rid of corrections in Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Someone emailed me a Word document that contains a record of corrections.  That is, it shows some text "crossed out" and other text added.  It looks like it's keeping track of 2 different versions of the document.  I am trying to export it to a PDF and even in the PDF these corrections are showing up.  How do I get rid of this and just show the final version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature is called Track Changes, which at least on OS X is in the Tools menu (or accesible from the Reviewing toolbar). You have two options, the most straightforward is just accept all changes (Accept or Reject Changes > Accept all changes). You can also disable showing changes in printed documents if you want to keep these changes - available from the Highlight changes dialog.

Comment: Accepting all changes is also useful if you will be making changes yourself, and/or forwarding the document (still in Word format) to anyone else.

Answer (score 6):

Turn off "Track changes" (how depends on your version of Word!).  In Word 2007, it's the Review ribbon, Track Changes button.

In Word 2007 you may also want to use the Document Inspector (Office button top-left, Prepare, Inspect Properties) to remove metadata that isn't part of the document body.

Then save to PDF.

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+SHIFT+E turns off "Track Changes."

That should allow you to output it cleanly.

**Edit**:  Nope.  I lied. The Reviewing Toolbar should show itself.  On there is a drop-down with "Final Showing Markup", "Final", etc.  Choose "Final" and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + V + A
toggles the view of your corrections

Comment: This should probably be Alt+V followed by Alt+A.